# Replace letter in word

Tags: python

If the guess is correct it will replace the letter with '-'. in the for loop how can i store the previous result and do a update with the new result?

```
import random

WORDS = ('linux', 'windows')
correct_word = random.choice(WORDS)


for n in range(5):
    guess = input('Enter a letter: ')
    letter = ''.join(x if x in guess else '-' for x in correct_word)

    if letter in correct_word:
        print("So far you have: ", letter)

    else:
        print("So far you have: ", letter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping the letters guessed so far in a variable, like this (I removed the `if` statement because both branches do the same thing). Also added input validation:

```
import random

WORDS = ("linux", "windows")
correct_word = random.choice(WORDS)

def get_single_letter_input():
    while True:
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if len(guess) == 1:
            return guess

word_so_far = "".join("-" for letter in correct_word)
for n in range(5):
    guess = get_single_letter_input()
    word_so_far = "".join(x if x in guess else word_so_far[i]
                          for i, x in enumerate(correct_word))

    print(f"So far you have: {word_so_far}")
```

Comment: for this statement letter = ''.join(x if x in guess else '-' for x in correct_word) it mean only replaced 1 time can i say that? what you did was replace the word_so_far index everytime it loop right?

Comment: @FufuAlex Yes, that line initialises `word_so_far` as "-----", a word of all dashes the same length as the correct word

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a regex replacement with `re.sub`.  This answer assumes that you would be OK with using `correct_word` itself to maintain the state, by being updated with dashes for each matching letter which the user might choose.

```
import random

WORDS = ('linux', 'windows')
correct_word = random.choice(WORDS)

for n in range(5):
    guess = input('Enter a letter: ')

    if len(guess) > 1 or len(guess) == 0
        print("Please choose a single letter only")

    if letter in correct_word:
        print("Correct choice")
        correct_word = re.sub(guess, '-', correct_word)

    else:
        print("Letter not present")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your guessed word in a variable. Also I would recommend not to use fixed range as you do, but get the length of chosen word

```
def guess():
    words = ('linux', 'windows')
    correct_word = random.choice(words)
    guessed_word = ["-" for letter in correct_word]
    for n in range(len(correct_word)):
        guess = input('Enter a letter: ')
        for i in range(len(correct_word)):
            if correct_word[i] == guess:
                guessed_word[i] = guess
        print("So far you have: ", "".join(x for x in guessed_word))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick draft for you, I strong believe that you can implement your fully idea:

```
import random

WORDS = ('linux', 'windows')
correct_word = random.choice(WORDS)

question = list( '-' * len(correct_word))
for n in range(5):
    guess = input('Enter a letter: ')
    for index, letter in enumerate(correct_word):
        if letter is guess:
            question[index] = letter
    print("So far you have: ", ''.join(question))
```

Comment: I already did as what u gave. I just want to understand a new method to get the result. thank anyway

Comment: the first I made a list like this to hide the *correct_word*

Example:
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
(the '-' based on length of the *correct_word*)

The we go to the loop:
 The outer loop is 5 times it is your idea

The inner loop is mine. it is really simple:

   If the *letter* is as same as "guess" (it mean your guess is correct) then I simply replace the element "-" in *question* that has same index with *correct_word* (because each element in *correct_word* is each element in *question* with same position)

 Finally I simple print *question*

You can also add more features ...